# How can I print a footnote in an \sout from ulem?

Tags: footnotes, ulem

So I have a text that gets striked out through the `\sout` of package ulem. I learned I need to put the `\footnote` in an `\mbox` to protect it from getting broken, but the foot note is not printed:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{ulem}
\begin{document}
    \sout{Test\mbox{\footnote{Footnote}} Text.}
    
    \sout{Test}\footnote{Footnote} \sout{Text.}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### The easy way

Use lualatex + lua-ul:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[soul]{lua-ul}
\begin{document}
    \st{Test\footnote{Footnote} Text.}
\end{document}
```

[image]

### With ulem

Use \footnotemark/\footnotetext (the second should be near the mark to avoid that it moves to the next page):

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{ulem}
\begin{document}
    \sout{Test\mbox{\footnotemark}}\footnotetext{Footnote}\sout{ Text.}
    
\end{document}
```